# Does a digitally signed xml keep its signature after encoding?

Tags: soap, base64, certificate, soapui

I am sending xml files to a web service that are digitally signed. The soap communication is valid but the response tells me that the signature isn't.
The files are sent in base64 encoding. Would that interfere with the signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base64 is a bit-by-bit representation of your data. Just encoded, not modified. So if the signature is valid on your side but not on the other it might be an trust issue:

- Is the signer certificate trusted?

  - Is the issuer of the signer certificate trusted?

    - Is the root certificate of the signature certificate known and trusted?

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Im speaking to the owners of the webservice and i'm making sure they trust my certificate.

Comment: Any feedback yet?

Comment: Yes, turns out my XML's are being signed as a type XAdES_BES:1.3.2 and i need it signed as one of these two :  XAdES - Epes or XAdES - XL. Web service documentation doesn't specify this, had to open a ticket with support. And my certificate was validated by the site itself which led to further confusion. Slowly sorting it out :)